# Calculate number of occurrence in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

Would like to determine the number of repeated occurrence in Column B and fill in the number accordingly in Column X as shown in the attached image. Wondering what is the best way to do it, either using Excel function or VBA.

Appreciate if someone can assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,B2)
```

Put it into cell `X2` and fill down

Comment: Hi Thanks, got it. I guess the right formula is `=COUNTIF(B:B,B2)` and put in cell `X2` to fill down